# Branding is not applying in Salesforce Community Registration

Tags: community, registration

I am setting up a community in salesforce. For the Login/ Registration part, I am trying to use branding options. It looks fine in Login and Forgot Password screens. But in Registration, it is not getting applied.

Would anyone please let me know why this is happening. Is there anything that I am missing?

This is how my registration screen looks like :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default community registration page will not show logo. You have to change registration page in Workspace->Administration -> Login and Registration.
[image]

Default registration page is shown from Visual Force Page **CommunitiesSelfReg**. Either you can change this page to add logo or create new lightning component and set with Community Builder Page.